# Wordpress created Collation Mess and is now unable to read it since MySQL8?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, character-encoding, collation, diacritics

I have a Wordpress site since 2009 and in the time being it created a real mess in the collations. I got:

- `latin1_swedish_ci` (never had word swedish on my site? Everything is in German)
- `latin1_german2_ci`
- `utf8mb3_general_ci`
- `utf8mb3_unicode_ci`
- and even some `ascii_general_ci`

Now everything was fine until MySQL 8 came along.

Since the umlauts are now broken I looked into my database - and saw that they are also stored "wrong". I guess my Wordpress sent UTF-8 into some latin1 table.

But until now everything displayed fine.

So I tried to update the whole database collation - which I recognized does not influence the single table collation.

And when I try to change a single table collation (my idea is to make them all `utf-8_mb4_general_ci` - it gives me a warning that characters may be changed - and can not be reverted.

So I am little hesitant how to proceed from here. And unsure. Will converting the collations in all tables solve the problem?

I can add a:

```php
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

to my `wpconfig`

But as I have more than 1.000 posts on the website I got a horror to have to do it all manually afterwards because I screwed up.

Also there are 241 tables in the database, so it may take some time do them all by one.

My goal is to display the umlauts äöüß and so on correctly in my WP front- and backend again.

Comment: Before you continue, do you have a backup of the database before anything was changed. Even if not, take one now before going any further. So you can at-least play with another copy of it and downgrade to an older MySQL should it be needed.

Comment: before you start anything make a backup to restore everything if something gets wrong. usually you connect with the same character set collation get all data and connection with a second connection with utf8mb4 and utf9mb4_unicode_ci and send the data to a table with the same structure only with the utf8mb4 character set and same collation

Comment: @wharfdale Yes, I did that. Thanks for mentioning! (Found on my hoster how to do a sql backup on the fly). Unfortunally a downgrade to older mysql will not be possible I think, as support for the sql version 5 ends - and 8 is now the new kid on the block. But with the backup I can at least be sure that I can go back if I totally mess it up ;-) (Has to be 10 years since I used mysql dump, but I can figure that one out again.)

Comment: @nbk I think that how it should work (use the same character set collation) to send and to store. But in my case it unfortunally did not. Or maybe I am not really getting your answer? (which can be very likely the case ;-) ).

Comment: write a simple python script with twio connection and two different character sets and collations according to whqat you have prior in your backup, the rest is a simple select and insert, most of that what i recommend is already here on the page

Comment: "broken" -- which way?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

I found this "[Converting Database Character Sets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets)" from the WordPress Codex.  It appears to be happening for sites that are older than 2010 when this was written. It seems to describe what you'd need to do to fix your data to get proper utf8 support.

A key section stands out:

> Every site is different when it comes to database charset conversions
> [...]
> If you are reading this now then you will probably have to do this by hand, as most of the plugins written for the purpose have stopped working in the years since WP changed its default behavior.

and this is a quick summary of the technique they suggest:

> Converting columns to blob, then back to original format with new charset
> [...]
> The solution is to first convert all text-containing fields to their binary ("BLOB") counterpart data-type (which have no charset), then alter them back to their normal data-type along with the desired new character set.

You may also be interested in this other discussion "[Please explain how WordPress works with MySQL character set and collation at a low level](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266805/please-explain-how-wordpress-works-with-mysql-character-set-and-collation-at-a-l)" and the replies. It mentions a system that WP uses to detect what character set to use. That may have been what malfunctioned.

It would also seem [you're not the only person to run into this kind of thing with MYSQL 8](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2021/10/15/wordpress-latin1-and-utf-8-part-2/).

Good luck! I found this while trying to help someone else with weird character encodings that occurred on their older posts, not specifically for UTF8 support, but it seems to be the same rough problem.

Comment: As I am new I can't upvote your answer, but this is what I will try with  a clone of my database. I found a working solution for now (see my answer), but for the future I think it will be better to have it all in UTF8. Thanks for the time you took and the detailed and helpful answer! :-) Cheers and all the best! André

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for now (with the help of my hosters support - they were really kind and helpful):

We changed in my wp-config

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

to

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'latin1');
```

and that did the trick for now. My site works again and the umlauts are displaying correctly.

So now I can take some time and "recode" a clone of my database to UTF-8 - as I think this will be more future - proof.

Thanks for all the help! :-)

Greetings,

André